# convert image to grayscale node

Tags: node.js, opencv

im using the library Opencv-wasm and in this code:

```
async __img_to_grayscale(img) {
        // Convert the input image to grayscale
        const grayscaleImage = new cv.Mat();
        cv.cvtColor(img, grayscaleImage, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        return grayscaleImage;
    }
```

the line cv.cvtcolor... return `RuntimeError: abort(6653992).`

note that `img` is a opencv-wasm Mat like `grayscaleImage`

How can i fix this?

i tried to change `grayscaleImage` to `img` and also change `cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` to other possible parameters.